# Grafana - Toggle off series by default

Tags: grafana

Is there any way to toggle off series by default in Grafana? 
Not hide them permanently, I just want to show them as disabled the first time the page is accessed.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean by this, but on the `Metrics` editor of each dashboard, next to each series, there is a clickable _eyeball_. Clicking on that will hide the series from the graph. Simply same the dashboard with the series hidden, and on load, it will still be hidden, and can be enabled by again clicking the eyeball.

Comment: No, I don't want to hide them that way, I want to do this the same way you toggle a plot - clicking on the name.

Comment: @RaúlGarcía did you find anything around it ?

Comment: @GauravShah no, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible at the time of writing 2016-12-21 / grafana version 4.

There is an open issue here: 
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/4645

Comment: did you find any alternative later on ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible since Grafana 6.5.0-beta1.

Use the Series Override feature to set the Hidden Series value for the series you wish to hide or display.

[image: setting the hidden state for series "b" in an override]

[image: the resulting chart with "b" hidden]